# How to make pgfplots to center a text in a xticklabel

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfplots

In `pgfplots` I've used the `text width` option in the definition of `xticklabel style` and I wonder how to center the labels text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the key `align=center` in addition to `text width`.

Comment: Hi Martin! I'd tried that before but got the following error: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: @Matthias: That means you're using an old version of TikZ. If you're using the version of TeXLive shipped with Ubuntu, you should switch to the direct installation from the TeXLive website, as the Ubuntu version is hopelessly outdated. If you're using a different install, try updating the PGF/TikZ package.

Comment: Thanks for that remark! I didnt realize that there was a new version of tikZ. Now align=center works